# What is the rule for the punctuation marks for a bicyclo compound?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

What is the rule for the punctuation marks within the bracketed figures for a bicyclo compound? Is it a 'dot' or 'comma'? In some books there are commas whereas dots in some others.

Comment: Why in the world did you roll back?

Comment: Mostly dot is used, so think dot is **more** correct

Comment: Do you have some examples of those structures that you are talking about?

Comment: I am talking of all bicyclo compunds as a whole. I am confused because commas and dots are qually distrbuted all over the net and books !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)* reads as follows:

> **P-16.2.2** Full stops
>
> Full stops are used to separate numbers that denote lengths of bridges in polyalicyclic names constructed according to the von Baeyer system (…) and of chain lengths between spiro atoms in von Baeyer spiro names (…).

Examples:
bicyclo[3.2.1]octane
6-oxaspiro[4.5]decane